# How to download files from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform

I have this working code which read and print out a list of file name from Google Bucket in C#.

```
GoogleCredential credential = null;
using (var jsonStream = new FileStream(@"D:\data.json", FileMode.Open,
    FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(jsonStream);
}
var storageClient = StorageClient.Create(credential);

// List objects
foreach (var obj in storageClient.ListObjects(bucketName, ""))
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
}
```

My question is how to I auto download this list of files into my computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it by using `DownloadObject` method from `StorageClient` object.